# Uncertainty in the relativistic energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, energy, error-analysis

Relativistic energy is given by formula,

$$E^2 = P^2+m^2$$
according to this  is it correct to denote the relation between uncertainty in the energy and momentum by,

$$E\Delta E  = P \Delta P$$
$$\Delta E = \frac{P}{E} \Delta P$$
or one should use formula
$$\Delta E = \sqrt{\left<E^2\right> - \left<E\right>^2}$$

---

I think this answer my question the second relation is more appropriate. However I am just curious to know that whether both  equations will give same change in energy (E). Since using first formula..

$$\Delta E = \frac{P}{E} \Delta P$$
we can get uncertainty relation,
$$\Delta E = V \Delta P$$
$$\Delta t \Delta E = \Delta X \Delta P$$

Answer (score 1):

The equations that you are asking about serve different purposes.

$\Delta E =\frac pE \Delta p$ relates a change in energy to a change in momentum. The relationship *can* be used to relate an uncertainty in $E$ to an uncertainty in $p$, but that is only one use for the equation.

$\Delta E =\sqrt{\langle E^2\rangle - \langle E\rangle^2}$ is specifically about uncertainty. It gives the standard deviation of $E$ in terms of the mean square value of $E$ and the square of the mean value of $E$. You could use this relationship to find the standard deviation in $E$ if you had many measurements of $E$.